# What's wrong with my binary search?

Tags: java, binary-search

I've just started learning Java (this is my first time programming in it). Where the print statement is (purely for test purposes), the code outputs the mid repeatedly without ever changing it. I've thought about it for several hours and cannot figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*class containing binary search algorithm*/
public class BinarySearch {
    /*conducts a binary search as specified by user*/
    public static int binarySearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    int length = list.length; 
    /*last point of list*/
    int top = length-1;       
    /*first point of list*/
    int bottom = 0;    
    /*starting midpoint of list*/
    int mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom)/2);
    /*binary search*/
    while(bottom < top) {
        if((int)queryValue == (int)list[mid]) {
        return mid;
        }
        else if(queryValue > list[mid]) {
         bottom = mid;
         mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom) / 2);
         StdOut.print(mid);
        }
        else {
         top = mid;
         mid = (top + bottom) / 2;
         }
    }
    /*returns -1 if user value not found*/
    return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your value is greater than the midpoint, then the midpoint is eliminated.  Advance `bottom` one past the current `mid`:

```
bottom = mid + 1;
```

Similarly for the less than the midpoint case, advance `top` one before the current `mid`:

```
top = mid - 1;
```

Otherwise, you may get a case where `bottom` and `top` never cross each other.

Also, binary search works only when the input is already sorted.  Please confirm/ensure that your array is already sorted.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the middle points, but the algorithm doesn't work for the first and last positions in the array still.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide data that you use for testing.
As for now, I see that for the following input it will hang:
`binarySearch(9, new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})`
mid will be 7
It's because (7+8)/2 = 7 because you work with int
Try to replace:
`mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom) / 2);`
with
`mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom) / 2.0);`
It will resolve the issue.
Good luck!

Updated the code to take into account edge cases:

```
public static int binarySearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    int length = list.length;
    /*last point of list*/
    int top = length-1;
    /*first point of list*/
    int bottom = 0;
    /*starting midpoint of list*/
    int mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom)/2.0);
    /*binary search*/
    do {
        if (queryValue > list[mid]) {
            bottom = mid;
            mid = (int)Math.ceil((top + bottom) / 2.0);
            System.out.println(mid);
        } else {
            top = mid;
            mid = (int)Math.floor((top + bottom) / 2.0);
            System.out.println(mid);
        }
        if(queryValue == list[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
    } while (mid < top && mid > bottom);
    /*returns -1 if user value not found*/
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the case of where the key is the last position in the array, but the algorithm still doesn't work for the first position.

Comment: It would be better if you provide data that you use for testing.

Comment: I used 8 as the key with [8, 9, 10] as the array.

Comment: It now seems to work in almost every case, except when there are three numbers and the key is the middle value. For example, the key is 8 with [7, 8, 9] as the array.

Comment: I changed the while loop conditional from an and to an or. As far as I've tested it seems to work now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int binarySearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    int length = list.length;
    /*last point of list*/
    int top = length-1;
    /*first point of list*/
    int bottom = 0;
    /*starting midpoint of list*/
    int mid = (int)Math.round((top + bottom)/2.0);
    /*binary search*/
    do {
        if (queryValue > list[mid]) {
            bottom = mid;
            mid = (int)Math.ceil((top + bottom) / 2.0);
            System.out.println(mid);
        } else {
            top = mid;
            mid = (int)Math.floor((top + bottom) / 2.0);
            System.out.println(mid);
        }
        if(queryValue == list[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
    } while (mid < top || mid > bottom);
    /*returns -1 if user value not found*/
    return -1;
}
```